# How get images from Firebase Storage?

Tags: flutter

I have an application that uses a lot of images. I would like to store these images outside the ios/android device. I decided to store some of the images in firebase storage. How can I get images using storage? Like this

```
Image.asset(brand.model[0].model_image[index].image,
          fit: BoxFit.fill),
```

Comment: Firebase Storage or alternative of that in AWS. Even imgur can be used.

Comment: thanks, I already started using firebase storage

Answer (score 0):

Its better to store all these images in your app directory it will increase your app size but the images will load faster as they will be in the app itself plus help in reducing the data usage for the user as the app will not download the images on app launch but still if you want to keep the images in a outside server Firebase Storage will be the best use.

Comment: When I released my application on testflight I found out that the application weighs 850MB, it's too much

Comment: You know how can I get images from firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the assets separately in a folder called assets and you can use that from there. The only thing you need to do is specify the path in pubsec.yaml file to access the images.

I would always do it like.

```
assets
  |_____images
  |_____svgs
  |_____audios
```

Hope this will help you to keep it organized.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also into Flutter and Firebase, trying to keep the actual application as small as possible. I could write everything out right here, but the creators of FlutterFire have a website that explains every step in detail. This link below will direct you to the first step of using cloud storage.

Link: [FlutterFire Cloud Storage](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/overview)

Comment: I already tried to call images with this method, unfortunately I get null. 
maybe I'm using the method in the wrong context. I may have configured firebase incorrectly